# Mschart get multiple series from Database

Tags: c#, mschart

Hello I'm trying to populate a mschart from sql but even if the series have different values the chart is the same. So all the series have the same line overlapping each other.

```
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         DataTable table = new DataTable();

        // Add three columns to the table.
        table.Columns.Add("Channel", typeof(String));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(String));
        table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(Int32));


        // Add data rows to the table.
        while (rdr.Read())
        {

            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { rdr[0], rdr[1], rdr[2] });

        }
        chart1.DataSource = table;
        //add series
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (chart1.Series.Where(x => x.Name == table.Rows[i][0].ToString()).Count() > 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                chart1.Series.Add(table.Rows[i][0].ToString());

            }
        }
        //set x,y axis for each series
        for (int i = 0; i < chart1.Series.Count; i++)
        {

            chart1.Series[i].XValueMember = "Date";
            chart1.Series[i].YValueMembers = "Value";

            chart1.Series[i].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;

        }
        chart1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Well all have the same `DataSource` and X and Y value members, show they would all end up displaying the same thing ! !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found Another way without databinding

```
   #region get values from database
        string query = "declare @start datetime, @end datetime select @start = '" + start + "', @end = '" + end + "' select Name,DataDT,Rating,DataGroupID from DATA inner join Channels on Channels.ID = DATA.ChannelID where DataDT >= @start and DataDT < @end and ChannelID<'4'";
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        sqlCon = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConectionString);
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        // Add three columns to the table.
        table.Columns.Add("Channel", typeof(String));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(String));
        table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(Int32));

        // Add data rows to the table.
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { rdr[0], rdr[1], rdr[2] });
        }
        sqlCon.Close();


        #endregion



        // Create a data series


        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (chart1.Series.Where(x => x.Name == table.Rows[i][0].ToString()).Count() > 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                Series series = new Series(table.Rows[i][0].ToString());
                chart1.Series.Add(series);

            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (Series series in chart1.Series)
            {
                if (table.Rows[i][0].ToString() == series.Name)
                {
                    series.Points.AddXY(Convert.ToDateTime(table.Rows[i][1]).ToShortTimeString(),Convert.ToDouble(table.Rows[i][2]));
                }

            }
        }
        //Set Properties for chart series
        for (int i = 0; i < chart1.Series.Count; i++)
        {

            chart1.Series[i].XValueMember = "Date";
            chart1.Series[i].YValueMembers = "Value";

            chart1.Series[i].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series[i].XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
            chart1.Series[i].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

            chart1.Series[i].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Star10;
            chart1.Series[i].MarkerSize = 8;
            chart1.Series[i].MarkerColor = chart1.Series[0].BorderColor;
            chart1.Series[i].BorderWidth = 3;
            chart1.Series[i].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            chart1.Series[i].ToolTip = "#VALY => #AXISLABEL";
        }

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try out below code

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

sqlConnection.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
table.Load(rdr);        

Chart1.DataBindCrossTable(table.AsEnumerable(), "Channel", "Date", "Value", "");

for (int i = 0; i < Chart1.Series.Count; i++)
{
   LegendItem legendItem = new LegendItem();
   legendItem.Name = Chart1.Series[i].Name;
   legendItem.BorderWidth = 1;
   legendItem.ShadowOffset = 1;
   legendItem.Color = Color.FromName(Chart1.Series[i].Color.Name.ToString());

   Chart1.Series[i].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;
   Chart1.Series[i].BorderWidth = 3;
   Chart1.Series[i].ToolTip = "#VALY/#VALY2 => #AXISLABEL";
   Chart1.Series[i].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
   Chart1.Series[i].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
}
```

NOTE : its advisable never to increase the default timeout other then your test system due to performance issues